# How to export Mapnik style to XML?

Tags: python, style, mapnik, xml

I would like to create Mapnik style using Python API and export it to XML-file. Creating style part is clear enough API has sufficient documentation. But I wasn't able to find function that does the import of created style to XML. Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapnik.save_map()`

```
import mapnik
m = mapnik.Map(1440,800)
# ... add styling and layers ...
mapnik.save_map(m, "output.xml")
```

Comment: By the way, I found the Mapnik Python documentation to be lacking a lot as well. I found a search engine for Python code called [Nullege](http://nullege.com/codes/search/mapnik.save_map), it helps a lot in discovering Mapnik features and how to use them.